# i want to total in the end of quiz, how to do that?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function checkValue(option) {
        if (option == "4") {
            alert("Correct");
        }
        else {
            alert("False, Option (4) is the Correct Answer.")
        }
    }
    //-->
</script>

<h3>1.  What does HTML stand for?</h3> <br /><br />

1. <input type="radio" name="fav_color1" value="1" onclick="checkValue(this.value);"   /> Hyper Text Markup Languages <br /> <br />
2. <input type="radio" name="fav_color1" value="2" onclick="checkValue(this.value);" /> Highest Text Markup Language <br /> <br />
3. <input type="radio" name="fav_color1" value="3" onclick="checkValue(this.value);" /> Hyper Total Markup Language <br /> <br />
4. <input type="radio" name="fav_color1" value="4" onclick="checkValue(this.value);" /> Hyper Text Markup Language <br /> <br />
```

Comment: Everybody knows that HTML stands for **H**ow **T**o **M**eet **L**adies.

Comment: Are you very new to programming? Your code snippet don't show any attempt at all

Comment: @Rehan I can't really tell what you are asking, there needs to be a more to your question. Does your page contain all of the questions?  Are you submitting the page back to the server and returning a count or correct answers or do you want the count to be assessed on the client side? As it is I am afraid that this is not a question.

Comment: yes @Richbits exactly how can i send you code , i am in new in it.

Comment: @Rehan you can paste it in the question (amending to remove repeat or irrelevant code). If you want to reference additional code, reference github or gist.github.com or pastebin.com. It also helps to show that you have thought about an answer or tried to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks @Richbits Here is my file's link https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b7de4e20c6e8d471caa6

Comment: Sir @Vucko This is Link https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b7de4e20c6e8d471caa6

Comment: Sir @LeeGary https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b7de4e20c6e8d471caa6

Comment: If you are doing it in 3 separate html pages, you would need to store the score on the server. If you want to do it on a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application, declare a var and keep track of the score as the user answers

Answer (score 0):

From what you have there it looks like you just have 3 html pages with a bit of javascript on each to alert the correct answer. After each page you are calling a new static page.

There are three options:

1. Wrap the input fields in a form with a submit button. On submitting that form, the server can process the answer (using a serverside language such as php, ruby, python or .net) and then probably maintaining count in a hidden field in the form.
2. Write everything in one page of javascript. This could get complex depending on whether you show one question at a time or not. You can then either maintain a variable with score for each question as it is submitted, or just assess all questions in javascript at the end.
3. Finally (and I wouldn't advise this approach by any stretch), you could create a page for every combination of right and wrong, then call a different page depending on which answers were right or wrong previously. So it would work something like this: On q1.html instead of having a link to q2.html you would have a blank link which you interrupt with javascript. If the answer is correct, then open page q2.html but if incorrect open page q2_q1.html on each of those pages (q2.html and q2_q1.html you need to have similar functionality thereby resulting in 4 pages for question 3. Assuming that there are only 3 questions you only need to put together 11 pages (assuming you just want to show the total score on the last page). Its not scalable and not the right way to do it, but (uswould work using fairly simple js.